# Como escrever em json sem sobrescrever?

Tags: javascript, json

Como consigo escrever num arquivo, por exemplo o teste.json, concatenando com o que há nele (sem sobrescrever)? Estou fazendo dessa forma, no entanto, ele está sobrescrevendo.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = __dirname + '/teste.json';

const produto = {
    nome: 'Smartphone',
    preco: 1749.99,
    desconto: 0.15
};

fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(produto), err => {
    console.log(err || 'Arquivo salvo');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para adicionar conteúdo ao arquivo sem sobrescrever, você deve usar a função `appendFile()`.

A função `writeFile()` vai sempre substituir o arquivo por um novo.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = __dirname + '/teste.json';

const produto = {
    nome: 'Smartphone',
    preco: 1749.99,
    desconto: 0.15
};

fs.appendFile(file, JSON.stringify(produto), err => {
    console.log(err || 'Arquivo salvo');
});
```

Comment: Como consigo separar cada objeto por vírgula?

Comment: Você pode ler o arquivo, usar um `JSON.parse()` para converter os dados lidos para JSON, adicionar o objeto novo com um push, e depois escrever o arquivo (nesse caso, você poderia usar o writeFile mesmo, já que sobrescreveria com o objeto completo). Mas quanto maior o arquivo, mais lento seria...